# Run VB.NET application is silent for distribution

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, command-line, silent

I have created an application that installs and edits configuration settings for a 3rd party application. The application works fine but I need to prepare it for deployment, which means I need to edit it so that it can run silently. I've created it in Visual Studio 2012, if that makes any difference. It contains 3 `Messagebox.Show` for errors, that I suppose I should output to the error log, and the "Configuration Complete" prompt after success. There is a single button click to start the configuration function.

I have looked around and found only people trying to silently run other applications silently from within their code. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a Module to your project.

Change your [Startup Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17k74w0c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to "Sub Main" in `Project Properties>Application Tab`

Then add a Sub Main your module:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'call your program code here instead of from your button click
    End Sub

End Module
```

And yes you need to log your errors to a file instead of showing them in a Message Box

Comment: Will this allow me to still use the form or do I need to have the Sub Main decide to open the form or not based on command line arguments?

Comment: @SChase - yes you can optionally show the Form from here is not running silently. Just check command line args and if not specified to run silently show the form